# How does $\sin \theta \times \sin (\theta - \phi)$ become $\frac{\cos \phi - \cos (2\theta-\phi)}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

How does $\sin \theta \times \sin (\theta - \phi)$ become $\frac{\cos \phi - \cos (2\theta-\phi)}{2}$

Comment: I recommend using something other than $\varnothing$ for an angle, or number. It by convention (that I have never seen broken) is the empty set.

Comment: @PaulPlummer - the OP probably wanted to write $\phi$ here.

Comment: @TheDarkSide I could tell (and was about to submit an edit before someone got to it before I did), just letting the author know for any future posts.

Comment: @PaulPlummer Yeah.will do.Thanks

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly expanding the LHS would be a difficult way of going about it, since there would have to be so many simplifications. Instead, proceed as follows:

Use the identities

$$ \cos (A \pm B) = \cos A \cos B \mp \sin A \sin B$$

to arrive at

$$ \sin A \sin B = \left(\cos (A-B) - \cos (A+B) \right)/2$$

Then, your answer follows in one step. Note that cosine function is even under parity, so that $\cos(-\theta) = \cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

SUBSTITUTE FORMULE FOR
SIN(A-B) AND (SIN^2θ) AND
LASTLY GET THE EQUATION IN FORM OF COS(A-B)
:)

Comment: Don't use all caps. Also, it is frowned upon to post a photo in most instances (and I think this is one of those). You may want to learn some MathJax so that you can provide answer that are easier to read and better formated. A tutorial can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thx!!a lot!! the link was very helpful... @PaulPlummer

Comment: Thanks for writing this,i have upvoted it.But i will select the first answer as its simple.